# cryptographically random generation MIT library javascript

Tags: javascript, security, random, cryptography, numbers

I'm looking for a MIT licensed javascript library to generate cryptographically random numbers. 
I have to use to generate AES 128 keys, so the generator has to be something really good.
Unfortunately, all the (serious) library I found on Internet are GPL licensed and I can't use them for legal reasons. 
Do you know a usable library, which would be MIT licensed, or even better, public?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have any particular language preferences?

Comment: @Steve - he says JavaScript, yes?

Comment: https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes Does this helps?

Comment: Steve : yes javascript only. 
srijan : I know about gibberish-aes, but it does not provide a key generator (it only expects user input password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very similar to [Generate cryptographically strong pseudorandom numbers in Javascript?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20029/generate-cryptographically-strong-pseudorandom-numbers-in-javascript).

**JavaScript in a browser:**

In Firefox and Chrome there is an experimental API to do this: [`window.crypto.getRandomValues`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.crypto.getRandomValues).

Other in browser libraries are problematic, since gathering enough entropy in a browser is hard. So they often have a long startup time, or may produce low quality randomness.

A few random number generator libraries:

- [seedrandom.js](http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html) (BSD license)
- [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library (sjcl)](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.com/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.random.html) (Dual licensed BSD and GPL 2.0 or later)
- [clipperz  / javascript-crypto-library](https://github.com/clipperz/javascript-crypto-library) (AGPL license)

The first two probably meet your license requirement, since BSD is a permissive license. I've included the third for completeness.

**node.js:**

[`crypto.randomBytes`](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html)

Comment: I don't know if we can use BSD licensed. Anyway, your first link seems good, and I will submit it to our legal. In the meantime, I coded my own fortuna algorithm, but it has to be validated by security.

Comment: The main issue with implementing it yourself isn't the Fortuna part, but ensuring that it's not possible to generate data before enough initial entropy has accumulated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) - it's BSD-licensed, and I think well-respected - been around for 3+ years now.

Comment: I looked in crypto-js, but it does not seem to provide keygenerator.

Answer (score 0):

Since last time, the [MSR JavaScript Cryptography Library](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/29f9385d-da4c-479a-b2ea-2a7bb335d727/) has been published and it's exactly what I needed.

By the way, modern browsers now support some crypto natively (chrome supports cryptographically secure pseudo random numbers, and IE11 has even more functions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn302338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx